# LCD Installation freeze because of low voltage?

Tags: raspbian, power-supply, lcd, voltage

i try to install my LCD 3.5 waveshare, but when extracting the folder and use `sudo ./LCD35-show` it starts shortly and then freeze. I Got the thunder icon and the freezed screen. Might this be the problem? I connected my PI to a USB Laptop.

Comment: Does your USB laptop have 2.1A-capable ports?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a wall-based power supply that you can use or a powered USB hub that you can put between laptop and Pi?

Comment: @ Dmitry Grigoryev : I don't really know what this is, haha. I would say just a normal USB port ;) But do you guys think that under voltage is the reason why it fails??

Comment: Lightening bolt means under voltage.  You could conceivable get that if your load is trying to pull more amps than your power supply and handle.  Could also happen if the load is such that resistance in the supply causes a voltage drop when current increases. (V = IR, so even for small R the drop will get bigger as I increases.)